# Upload different unique Excel file for every Single Virtual user in load runner

Tags: performance-testing

I have a scenario in which every user when logs in to the web application has to fill a form. So we have an option to upload an excel file having all the bio data in it. When the user will upload this excel sheet e.g. this `.xlsx` file, our application will automatically fetch all the data from the file and enter all the data in all fields on the web page. I have recorded this script and when run in Controller with 1 user it uploads and enters all the entries well. But now my task is to upload 50 different unique excel files for 50 Virtual users - every unique single virtual user with unique 1 Excel file, so that we can have 50 different unique data entries on our web page as 50 different unique virtual users. In Parametrization load runner is not allowing me to attach different files as parameters, it says `check file format`. I am stuck I have searched it a lot but didn't get any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shotgun cross forum post from the lr-loadrunner google group where the question has been answered fully.   You can find the reference thread at

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lr-loadrunner/GOcEw7Ads-M